# Border with spacing in Java?

Tags: java, swing, border

I'm trying to make a border, which as been successful. I want there to be some spacing before the border starts. Using this code now, the border is wrapped very tight around the text box. This is what I want to do: [Ideal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L11m8.png)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    //Variables
    JFrame mainframe = new JFrame();
    mainframe.setSize(500, 435);
    JPanel cards = new JPanel(new CardLayout());
    CardLayout cl = (CardLayout)(cards.getLayout());
    mainframe.setTitle("Future Retro Gaming Launcher");
    //Screen1
    JPanel screen1 = new JPanel();
    JTextPane TextPaneScreen1 = new JTextPane();
    TextPaneScreen1.setEditable(false);
    TextPaneScreen1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(240, 240, 240));
    TextPaneScreen1.setText("Welcome to the install wizard  for Professor Phys!\n\nPlease agree to the following terms and click the next button to continue.");
    TextPaneScreen1.setSize(358, 48);
    TextPaneScreen1.setLocation(0, 0);
    TextPaneScreen1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
    TextPaneScreen1.setMargin(new Insets(3,3,3,3));
    screen1.add(TextPaneScreen1);
    cards.add(screen1);
    mainframe.add(cards);
    mainframe.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: Something like,         `TextPaneScreen1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 150));` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try creating a [compound border](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/BorderFactory.html#createCompoundBorder%28javax.swing.border.Border,%20javax.swing.border.Border%29) with your line border and an empty border:

```
BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black),
                                   BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5))
```

Comment: I think he wants the compound borders the other way around (see his image, the lines are the inner part of the border). This is still correct, though, so +1